# Alternating color rows based on values of cells

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I'd like to have a table with alternating colors of rows but rows with the same value should have unitary background color. Can I achieve such an effect with CSS?

Example:
[image]

Comment: No, not really. This is something you should handle while creating the table, put appropriate classes on the row elements, and apply the background color via those.

Comment: you can do that in javascript/jQuery, not sure if you can do this in css

Comment: @ShoyebSheikh I'd really appreciate it if you could write how to do that in JS/jQuery

Answer (score 0):

JQuery
(feel free to simplify and edit this)

```js
$(function() {
   let elems = $('tr:not(".head")');
   let count = 0;
  
   for (let i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
      let el = $(elems[i]),
          prev = $(elems[i-1]);
      
      let isEven = (count % 2 == 0);
      
      if (isEven) {
         el.css('background', 'red');
      } else {
         el.css('background', 'yellow');
      }

      if (el.text() == prev.text()) {
         let clr = prev.css('background');
         el.css('background', clr);
      } else {
        count++;
      }
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class="head">
  <th>One</th>
  <th>Two</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>8</td>
</tr>
  
</table>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! It's works but could you help me to upgrade your code a little bit? In the second column instead of 1,2,3 will be one, two, three and the function will color rows based only on values from first column, is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what your desired output would be?